# Type resolution with flatMap

Tags: scala, scala-cats, circe

why do i need to add the type annotation at the first line?
`c.get[List[String]]("primary-group")` is `Decoder.Result[List[String]]` after `flatMap` it should keep the top type and be `Decoder.Result[String]` but it changes to Either[DecodingFailure, String]. Why? Is the problem that it is `dependent type`?

```
  case class JWTPayload(primaryGroup: Group, groupMember: List[Group], name: String, pid: String)

  implicit val jwtPayloadDecoder: Decoder[JWTPayload] = Decoder.instance(c =>
    (
      c.get[List[String]]("primary-group").flatMap(l => if(l.size == 1) l.head.asRight else DecodingFailure("", c.history).asLeft) : Decoder.Result[String],
      c.get[List[String]]("group-member"),
      c.get[String]("name"),
      c.get[String]("pid")
    ).map4(
     JWTPayload
    )
  )
```

Without `: Decoder.Result[String` I get

```
Error:(43, 7) value map4 is not a member of (scala.util.Either[io.circe.DecodingFailure,String], io.circe.Decoder.Result[List[String]], io.circe.Decoder.Result[String], io.circe.Decoder.Result[String])
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value map4'?
    ).map4(
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a full answer but I hope it will provide some insights. The crucial part here is how `map4` is implemented. As of cats 0.9 it is done via `cats.syntax.TupleCartesianSyntax` trait and its implicit `catsSyntaxTuple4Cartesian` which wraps a 4-tuple into a `cats.syntax.Tuple4CartesianOps` class (in cats 1.0 "cartesian" was changed to "semigroupal"). This code is auto-generated for all tuples up to 22 by [Boilerplate.scala](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/v0.9.0/project/Boilerplate.scala). The auto-generated code looks something like this:

```
implicit def catsSyntaxTuple4Cartesian[F[_], A0, A1, A2, A3](t4: Tuple4[F[A0], F[A1], F[A2], F[A3]]): Tuple4CartesianOps[F, A0, A1, A2, A3] = new Tuple4CartesianOps(t4)


private[syntax] final class Tuple4CartesianOps[F[_], A0, A1, A2, A3](t4: Tuple4[F[A0], F[A1], F[A2], F[A3]]) {
  def map4[Z](f: (A0, A1, A2, A3) => Z)(implicit functor: Functor[F], cartesian: Cartesian[F]): F[Z] = Cartesian.map4(t4._1, t4._2, t4._3, t4._4)(f)
  def contramap4[Z](f: Z => (A0, A1, A2, A3))(implicit contravariant: Contravariant[F], cartesian: Cartesian[F]): F[Z] = Cartesian.contramap4(t4._1, t4._2, t4._3, t4._4)(f)
  def imap4[Z](f: (A0, A1, A2, A3) => Z)(g: Z => (A0, A1, A2, A3))(implicit invariant: Invariant[F], cartesian: Cartesian[F]): F[Z] = Cartesian.imap4(t4._1, t4._2, t4._3, t4._4)(f)(g)
  def apWith[Z](f: F[(A0, A1, A2, A3) => Z])(implicit apply: Apply[F]): F[Z] = apply.ap4(f)(t4._1, t4._2, t4._3, t4._4)
}
```

Note the `F[_]` (functor) type parameter. Effectively this code adds `map4` method to any 4-tuple where each inner type is the same functor over some types.

So assuming you did `import cats.implicits._`, after (partial) implicits resolution your code is actually something like this:

```
cats.implicits.catsSyntaxTuple4Cartesian[Decoder.Result, String, List[String], String, String](
  c.get[List[String]]("primary-group").flatMap(l => if (l.size == 1) l.head.asRight else DecodingFailure("", c.history).asLeft): Decoder.Result[String],
  c.get[List[String]]("group-member"),
  c.get[String]("name"),
  c.get[String]("pid")
).map4[JWTPayload](
  JWTPayload
)
```

When you don't specify `Decoder.Result[String]`, Scala compiler is not smart enough to get that it should split `Either[DecodingFailure, String]` into a functor type `Either[DecodingFailure, _]` and `String` and then

1. there will be matching `Functor` and `Cartesian` implicit objects (actually provided by the `cats.implicits` object via `cats.instances.AllInstances` and `cats.instances.EitherInstances` traits)
2. it would match the functor type used for other 3 fields in the tuple (i.e. `Decoder.Result[_]`).

So I think this behavior is a result of a combination of the fact that `map4` is added to 4-tuple via an implicit Ops-class and the fact that the underlying type is `Either` which is 2-places generic type rather than a simple `Functor`.

Comment: Strange behaviour me is that if I have


    type Result[A] = Either[DecodingFailure, A]

    val a: Result[String] = Right("123")
    // when I do not write type it is Either[DecodingFailure, Int]
    val defaultTypeInference = a.map(Integer.parseInt)
    // coerced to be Result[Int]
    val coercedToBeResult: Result[Int] = a.map(Integer.parseInt)


Why map of flatMap in this case do not preserve the Result type? I know this is not type just a type alias but anyway

Comment: @user1698641, I'm not sure I get your point. If I change your third line to something that uses `map` like `c.get[String]("name").map(x => x + x)`, it also stop to compile unless I provide an explicit type hint `Decoder.Result[String]`. The issue in this scenario is not that the type is lost when you do `flatMap`. Types `Result[A]` and `Either[DecodingFailure, A]` are really the same and the Scala compiler knows it. The issue is that this non-trivial **_split_** of the  `Either[_,_]` type into `Decoder.Result[_]` is lost and the Scala compiler is not smart enough to make it again on its own.